# Convert string to hex and xor it

Tags: ruby, string, hex, xor

I've got encrypted string (data)

> data = “i]\rD\004\025\027\004_~\002\006`HZ@UBY\Ku\002O2\003_MQB\020\007G~\004Q”

and key (in hex)

> key = “0x7f0b0014”

Plain text = key xor data

I tried to decrypt it in ruby,but i've failed below is the code of one of my try.

```
data = "i]\rD\004\025\027\004_~\002\006`HZ@UBY\\Ku\002O2\003_MQB\020\007G~\004Q"
key = "7f0b0014"


# key changed to an array with chars in int stored in new_key
p new_key = [key].pack("H*").split(//).each.map { |x|  x.ord } 
#pack("H*") used on array GIVES STRING FROM HEX #.each.map change every [value] of an array by value.ord
p new_data = [data].pack("H*").split(//).each.map { |x| x.ord }

nd = Array.new
i,j = 0, 0 
while i < new_data.length do
  while j < new_key.length do
    new_data[i] = new_data[i].to_i ^ new_key[j].to_i
    j+=1
  end
  j=0
  nd << new_data[i].chr
  i+=1
end
p new_data
p nd.join 

#OUTPUT = "M\xBD%\x14\x9EFaP\x8BL.HC\x96\xCBgn*"
```

I tried to:

- add a padding "000...." on the left of the key
- add a padding "....000" on the right of the key
- loop the key to the same lenght as data "7f0b00147f0b0014...7f0b0014"

The output should give me a some kind of a string in format "1227a5aa-ce82-4da8-9ba6-c49e809ba720".

Here is the working code, but key here was integer, not a string:

```
key = 52 # "R" 
data = "\005\006\006\003U\001UU\031WQ\f\006\031\000PU\f\031\rVU\002\031W\000\rQ\f\004\rVU\003\006\004"

new_data = Array.new
data.split(//).each do |e|
   new_data << (e.unpack("H*")[0].to_i(16) ^ key).chr
end

p new_data.join
#OUTPUT "1227a5aa-ce82-4da8-9ba6-c49e809ba720"
```

Comment: It’s just data xor key.

Comment: I suggest you: 1) change `i]\rD\004\025...~\00` to `data = "i]\rD\004\025...~\00"`; 2) change `0x7f0b0014` to `key = 0x7f0b0014`; and 3) and  move your first line to just after the definition of `key`, changing it to "`data xor key` produces the desired plaintext". There is a problem, however, as there is no string method `xor`. In general, when giving an example it's always helpful to assign a variable to each input (here `data` and `key`), so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Also, always show the example's desired result.